# Can Aptana Studio 3 display method / class documentation?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I was wondering if Aptana can be made to display a method's documentation if I hover over it? Is this possible, or have I been too spoiled by Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure it can display PHP API on hover and your local created doc about certain functions.
Make sure your Project Properties are set to PHP Project or the type you want to display doc from.

Comment: I'm using Ruby, but yeah, I have my project set as a Ruby Project. Is there anything else I need to do though? The api doc isn't showing up...